# chain / cassette / chainrings replacement ratios - how often to you usually replace cassettes & chainrings per number of replaced chains?

Tags: chain, cassette, chainring

I'm looking to get other riders experiences with how often cassettes and chainrings usually have to be replaced per the number of chain replacements.  On my 2 road bikes I usually find roughly the following:

```
1 cassette replacement per 3 or 4 chains

1 chainring set (both inner and outer) replacement per 5 or 6 chains
```

Is this is about what would be typically expected?

P.S. Yes, I understand cassettes and chainrings should be inspected for wear rather than replaced based on the corresponding number of chains.  Of course I check cassettes and chainrings for wear before replacement, but I'm still curious as to how often other riders are replacing cassettes and chainrings in comparison to chains.

Comment: Your numbers are about what I'd guess, from my experience.  I wouldn't expect to get much more precise.

Comment: Have a browse through the related and linked questions section on the right side of the page.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52592/ https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56768/ https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29216/ https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/  etc.

Comment: For my road bike a cassette is roughly 1.25 times the cost of a chain.  I tend to wear them both out and replace both at once.  Get about 3000-5000 km off them, though shifting can get a little sketchy at the end.

Comment: On my road bike, I get 8,000 to 15,000 km to a Dura-Ace chain. A cassette lasts 3 or 4 chains. I just about never wear out the chainrings on my bikes before selling them. I do 20,000-30,000 km a year and sell my bike after riding it for 2-4 years.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a survey, not a question.